# Is it possible to load a navigation property of a collection of entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a query that will return an array of entities like so:

```
var collection = db.Items.ToArray();
```

Is it possible to now load related data from these items all at once (not using lazy loading):

Here is the entity class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual SecondaryItem Secondary { get; set; }
}
```

I need to load every Secondary item in my `collection` AFTER I have retrieved the main items in the array, so I can't use the Include method on the original query.

Is this possible?

**Edit**: What I mean is that I would prefer to load them all in one query instead of one by one.

Comment: Please explain why can't you use `Include`. From your example, this limitation seems to be artifitial.

Comment: This is a simplified example, but basically in the real query I'm having some performance problems with the query when I have the Include because of the joins that it is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the following:

```
db.Items.Select(x => x.SecondaryItem).Distinct().Load();
```

The `DbContext` will take care of initializing all of the existing `Item.SecondaryItem` references with the corresponding objects.

Note than Duane's solution would work too; this is just a bit more optimized.

Comment: What is this Load method you are referencing? What namespace is it in?

Comment: It's an extension method: add `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: It's not the identity map which will ensure that the navigation property is set, but it is **Relationship Fix-up** together with **Relationship Span**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/03/tip-10-understanding-entity-framework-jargon.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Trying again, based on comment. Can you just pull them all with a second query?

```
var itemIds = collection.Select(i => i.ID);
var query = from s in db.SecondaryItems 
            where itemIds.Contains(s.ItemID) 
            select s;
```

Comment: Code First - I don't have an IsLoaded property or a Load() method.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't set the navigation properties of my original objects. It might be safe if I do that part manually though? I'm not sure?

Comment: @Dismissile: Because you were talking about performance problems in your question's comment be careful with using `Contains`. For long collections it is well-known performance killer as well. It will work though and also set the navigation properties automatically (see Diego's answer and the link in my comment below his answer).